# Unable to delete any tuple

Tags: php, mysql

Could you please point out modifications to the code, so that it **deletes some/all rows** as per the query.

```
<?php 

require_once ('config.php');

$mid = $_POST['mid'];
$pid = $_POST['pid'];

$sql = "DELETE * FROM assignment WHERE project_id = '$pid', member_id = '$mid'";

$retval = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if($retval)
    {
        die('Could not delete data: ' . mysqli_error());
    }            

echo "Deleted data successfully";

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Comment: use 'and' instead of comma(,) in where clauses

Comment: and though I am not familiar with php but, I believe the variable $retval will be true if the query gets executed, since there is an error in your mysql query the statements 'if' condition will not be executed and ultimately you are getting message as "Delete data cussessfully". even though the data has not been deleted. use if ( !$retval ) instead.

Comment: -> Has been Solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WHERE clause when used together with the `AND` logical operator, is only executed if ALL filter criteria specified are met.

```
$sql = "DELETE * FROM assignment WHERE project_id = '$pid' AND member_id = '$mid'";
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `,` and use `and`

```
$sql = "DELETE * FROM assignment WHERE project_id = '$pid' and member_id = '$mid'";
```